# Discord.js get 2nd mention

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have this command where I want to get the 2nd mention (Role2).

```
!command [Role1] [Role2]
```

I know that I can get the first role with this code:

```
const role1 = message.mentions.roles.first();
```

But I couldn't find anything for the 2nd mention, nor could anyone tell me how to do it.
I hope anyone can help me with this issue.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://github.com/AnIdiotsGuide/discordjs-bot-guide/blob/master/first-bot/command-with-arguments.md

Comment: I am trying to use `message.mentions.roles` but it doesn't work. When I assign this to a variable like this `const role = message.mentions.roles[0]` and log it onto the console its undefined.

Comment: Yeah Dave, because message.mentions.roles is a class "RoleManager" not an "Array", You can use `Array.from(message.mentions.roles.cache)` but it's better to use Mythical's answer at the bottom v

Comment: @MalikLahlou actually, it's a Collection

Comment: Also, that would give an array of arrays using Array.from()

Answer (score 1):

`message.mentions.roles` is a `Collection`, and that has a `.at()` method.

```js
const role2 = message.mentions.roles.at(1) // index 1 is the second value
```

Note the roles may not be in the right order, so it's a good idea to use regex, and map by getting from cache

```js
// import MessageMentions class from discord.js module
const roles = message.content.match(MessageMentions.ROLES_PATTERN).map(r => message.guild.roles.cache.get(r.slice(3, r.length - 1))
const role2 = roles[1]
```